# Calculating Integrated Values using Data from CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am reading data from multiple CSV files. In the example below, we are just using one file. The CSV contains two columns of data, 'EFT' and 'CTR'. After reading in the data, I am trying trying to calculate integrated values using the CTR values, and storing those calculated integrated values in a new column named ITCER. This whole process takes roughly 15 seconds, if I'm analyzing roughly 10,000 data points. Ideally, I will be analyzing 25,000 data points from 8 different files. Thus, it does take a bit of time. Does anyone have any advice on how to alter the code to calculate ITCER (integration part) to make it run faster.

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *
#### User input; run numbers - will be fed into the program as part of the file name..
files = [20135501]

#create dataframes to store data temporarily based on EFTs

ITCER = DataFrame()
b = []

####  process data path
shorts = ['Python/CSV/Run Files/' + str(i) + '.csv' for i in files]

#### reads process data
ferms = [pd.read_csv(s) for s in shorts]
csvDFs = [(ferm).apply(pd.Series.interpolate) for ferm in ferms]

for i in range(len(files)):    
#Calculations
    for j in range(len(ferms[i])):
        if j == 0:
            c = ferms[i].irow(j)['CTR [mM/h]']
        if j > 0:
            g = ferms[i].irow(j)['CTR [mM/h]']
            h = ferms[i].irow(j-1)['CTR [mM/h]']
            c = c + (g+h)/120000
        b.append(c)    
        itcer = ITCER.append(b)         
    eft = csvDFs[i]['EFT (h)']

#insert calculations
    csvDFs[i]['EFT'] = eft
    csvDFs[i]['ITCER'] = itcer

#keep specific columns and then save file in folder
    csvDFs[i] = csvDFs[i][['EFT','ITCER']]
    csvDFs[i].to_csv('Python/CSV/Test/'+ str(files[i])+'.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: You use a dataframe by looping over the rows cell by cell. Try using the vector functions that are offered to you.

Comment: 'c' looks like the cumsum of 'CTR [mM/h]' + 1-shift 'CTR [mM/h]' / 120000

Comment: @Boud is right, pls post a sample of a file; your inner loop looks like it can be vectorized which offers great speedups here.